# Plum tree leaves not forming

Tags: trees, leaves, plums

Our usually well performing Lusia plum tree is having issues with forming new leaves.
Half of the tree is doing just fine, upper parts.
But the rest is like this: please help
[image: leaves]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?  please inspect the distorted growth, preferably with a magnifying glass - I see fine webbing stretched between the deformed shoots...you may find the creature that created the webbing if you look closely enough

Comment: New Zealand, sorry. Taupo. Wow thank you, I didn't even notice the webbing! I assumed it would be spiders. I'll have a look now.

Comment: It might just be a spider on the end of that branch, but if there's evidence of webbing around most or all the deformed shoots on the rest of the tree, then its likely to be connected to whatever the  problem is